# Submit hidden fields with listbox items that have been moved using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two list boxes that I can move items to and from using jQuery. A summary of the code follows:

```
<select multiple size="10" id="from">...</select>
<select multiple id="to" size="10" name="subitted array[]">...</select>
```

Some buttons that when clicked move the items from the above list boxes:

```
<a href="javascript:moveSelected('from', 'to')">&gt;</a>...
<a href="javascript:moveSelected('to', 'from')">&lt;</a> 
<a href="javascript:moveAll('to', 'from')" href="#">&lt;&lt;</a>
```

The jQuery functions:

```
function moveAll(from, to) {
    $('#'+from+' option').remove().appendTo('#'+to); 
}

function moveSelected(from, to) {
    $('#'+from+' option:selected').remove().appendTo('#'+to); 
}
```

I also have the following function that I call on submit:

```
<form name="selection" method="post" onSubmit="return selectAll()">... </form>

function selectAll() {
    $("select option").attr("selected","selected");
}
```

But this only returns by POST the values in the right list box. I would also like to submit other fields present in the form (e.g. hidden fields). How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dropdown lists are inside your form, you dotn need any special treatment, just submit your form and all fields inside it, will be send to your controller.

In JS:

```
$('#formId').submit();
```

In your html:

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

Any of this 2 options would suit your problem, if i understand workgly your problem, please let me know.

Also you should remove this code "onSubmit="return selectAll()" and leave form submit work normally, will send all your data into the form

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you're right in one thing - all I needed was that code. The hidden fields get sent. Don't know why I didn't think of that.

But there is something else that's wrong, though. Only the selected values are being sent from the list box. Not all the ones that are in the box. The jQuery code, sent them all. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. Not sure if this is the best way to do it but I added `onclick="selectAll()"` to the button tag and in the selectAll() method I got javascript to select all the entries in the second list box. All values are onw being passed by POST. Thanks for your time.